# Merge two corrupted copies of same file to fix errors / finding parts of files of same size that differ

Tags: diff

Having mirror copy of hard drive I noted few files became different one copy from another (by sha256 check). I would like to merge these two to several versions of file one of which I hope would be correct one. I assume files both could be corrupt. As theoretically number of combinations could be quite large, I imagine trying to merge manually first by

1. identifying parts of files that differ. Is there a tool to show differences of ranges of bytes/"frames" of arbitrary size? cmp/diff show only 1st different byte or long list of all bytes. I would like to be able to set frame to say 1kb and tool would output: differ on 34-41 frames, 1779-2005 frames etc.
2. taking all combinations of the above parts and merging them to several copies of a file.

I could not easily find by web search tools on Linux for any of 1 or 2. Maybe also there is some automation to task I want to do?